# っつー　at the end of a sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, nuances

What does っつー at the end of sentence mean, I get that its a form of と言う/っていう, but still don't quite understand use of it. And it isn't quotation.
some of the sentence I came across using them

私が知るわけないっつーの

自分でがんばれっつーの